# Python is there an equivalent of stringWithFormat: from Objective-C?

Tags: python, ios, string-formatting

Objective-C strings are immutable, just like Python strings, however there's a class method of NSString in Objective-c that allows creation of string using %@ format specifiers. Each %@ gets replaced by a string from the following list of arguments.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iBeacon major:%@ minor:%@", majorVersion, minorVersion ]
```

**Is there a way to get "stringWithFormat" behavior in Python?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [closest equivalent](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) is

```
mystring = "iBeacon major:%s minor:%s" % (majorVersion, minorVersion)
```

However, the recommended way to do it with Python 2.7+ is to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of the `%` method:

```
mystring = "iBeacon major:{} minor:{}".format(majorVersion, minorVersion)
```

Comment: meh I still like % formating and use it often, and they have now recanted on it being depreciated and eventually phased out ... that said +1 ... you just left out `"iBeacon major:{major} minor:{minor}".format(minor=minorVersion,major=majorVersion)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yeah, I still use `%` quite a bit because it's fewer characters. And yes, there a whole bunch of more advanced usages of both the `%` method and `str.format` I didn't cover here. The links I provided to the docs do go into them in detail, however.